# Swift: How to find out the size of a container view and position a label in the center programmatically?

Tags: ios, uiview, label, containers, center

I am having a container view with a label, The container view is added programmatically to the lower half of the superview with half of the size of the superview. I am setting the size like this:

```
testView.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height / 2)
```

[image]

(The orange square is the containerView and thats where I'd like to place the label - in the center of the container view)

That way it's half the size of the superview.
Now I'd like to position the label within the container view right in the center of it programmatically. Actually it should be animated with CGAffineTransform and moves to the center, but for the sake of my question it doesn't really matter.

I have tried several things but even a simple solution like self.testView.midX / midY doesn't work. It is not centered or the label is placed somewhere outside the container.

I have tried to get the views width and height:

```
let timerViewWidth = self.timerView.bounds.width
let timerViewHeight = self.timerView.bounds.height
```

And divide both by 2 to get the exact center of testView, but when I use these values the label is also placed somewhere else.

How can I center the label programmatically within the container view?

Comment: You should be looking at auto-layout and constraints, but if you really don't want to... you can use `testView.center = view.center`

Answer (score 0):

Just use autolayout to add `UILabel` to your container view (which I will call containerView).

```
let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//configure label the label as needed
containerView.addSubview(label)

containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0));
containerView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0));
```

If you don't want to use Autolayout just do what @DonMag suggested

```
testView.center = containerView.center
```

Also make sure that you add testView as subview of `containerView` and not some other view...